# Gitlab CI/CD: only build when certain files have changed, also when previous pipeline has failed

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

I’m creating multiple Docker builds in my CI/CD config of Gitlab and I’m trying to speed things up. I’ve got a couple of Docker services in my Gitlab repository and to avoid building them all on each CI/CD trigger, I’m using the following fragment in .gitlab-ci.yml to only build images when certain files have changed:

```
only:
    refs:
      - master
    changes:
      - myfiles/**/*
```

This works fine. Except when there’s a pipeline error (connection error during file upload for example). So when the pipeline is triggered again, certain services are not built because my files have not changed.

Can I somehow update the conditions that it needs to listen to file changes also when a pipeline error has occurred before?

Comment: if you relaunch the pipeline manually on `master`, it will trigger all the jobs even those waiting for changes.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? Manually triggering all jobs if a previous pipeline fails does not seem sustainable.